# Add a key and array to object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array called Cars. How do I get from this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "Car",
        "maxPerson": 4,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "Car",
        "maxPerson": 5,
    }
]
```

to this.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "Car",
        "maxPerson": 4,
        "owner": {
            "username": "jsmith",
            "firstname": "Joe",
            "lastname": "Smith"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "Car",
        "maxPerson": 5,
    }
]
```

Assuming I know the index of the item. I have tried:

```
const newOwner = {owner: {username: "jsmith", firstname: "Joe", "lastname": "Smith"};
Cars[index].push(newOwner)
```

but get:

```
Cars[index].push is not a function
```

Comment: `Object.assign(Cars[index], newOwner)` is the easiest option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cars[index]` is the object, so `Array.push()` doesn't work.

```
Cars[index] = { ...Cars[index], ...newOwner }
```

Answer (score 3):

`Cars[index]` is not an array, but an object, so it does not have a function `push`.

Just assign the `owner` property (if it does not exist yet, it will be added) of the object

```
Cars[index].owner = {username: "jsmith", firstname: "Joe", "lastname": "Smith"}.
```